# simple script for monitoring a mailserver

Tags: email, monitoring, postfix

I would like to use a bash script (python would be second best) to monitor regularly (hourly) if my mailserver is online and operating.

I know that there are dedicated solutions for this task (Nagios, ...) but I really need something simple that I can use as a cronjob. Only to see the mailserver is alive.

I know how to talk with a mailserver with telnet, ie:

```
telnet mail.foo.org 25
EHLO example.com
mail from:
rcpt to:
...
```

but this is interactive. Is it possible to check with a script that the mailserver is communicating? Obviously, I don't want to go the whole way and actually send an email. I just want to test that the mailserver is responding.

Comment: Is checking if the server is enough? Does the mailserver can crash alone?

Comment: Check out the code snippet [in my answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124267/19575)

Comment: A system management tool like chef or puppet would be a good tool to make sure it stays running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `nc` to test a SMTP mail server like so:

```
$ nc -w 5 mail.mydom.com 25 << EOF
HELO mail.mydom.com
QUIT
EOF
```

**NOTE:** The options `-w 5` tell `nc` to wait at most 5 seconds. The server to monitor is `mail.mydom.com` and `25` is the port we're connecting to.

You can also use this form of the above if you find your server is having issues with the `HELO`:

```
$ echo "QUIT" | nc -w 5 mail.mydom.com 25
```

**NOTE:** This form works well with both Postfix and Sendmail!

#### Example

Here I'm connecting to my mail server.

```
$ echo "QUIT" | nc -w 5 mail.bubba.net 25
220 bubba.net ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3; Sat, 19 Apr 2014 16:31:44 -0400
221 2.0.0 bubba.net closing connection
$
```

If you check the status returned by this operation:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

However if nothing at the other ends accepts our connection:

```
$ echo QUIT | nc -w5 localhost 25
Ncat: Connection refused.
$
```

Checking the status returned from this:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

#### Putting it together

Here's my version of a script called `mail_chkr.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Checking Mail Server #1"
echo "QUIT" | nc -w 5 mail.bubba.net 25 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo "mail server #1 is UP"
else
  echo "mail server #1 is DOWN"
fi

echo "Checking Mail Server #2"
echo "QUIT" | nc -w 5 localhost 25 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo "mail server #2 is UP"
else
  echo "mail server #2 is DOWN"
fi
```

Running it:

```
$ ./mail_chkr.bash 
Checking Mail Server #1
mail server #1 is UP
Checking Mail Server #2
Ncat: Connection refused.
mail server #2 is DOWN
```

Comment: I think it's cleaner to send a single `.` to terminate the SMTP session, rather than `EOF` after the `HELO`.

Comment: @Bananguin - actually when I tried that it gave me this error: `500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: "."`. Adding a QUIT however worked, so I'll add that.

Comment: Works great. I have added `-w 5` for `nc` as a timeout of 5 sec. Otherwise it seems to hang indefinitely when it cannot reach the server.

Comment: @user1968963 - Yes I meant to mention that. I'll add it into the answer.

Comment: @slm - on the mailserver, I see these messages in the log: `postfix/smtpd  improper command pipelining after HELO from unknown: QUIT\n`. Can we get rid of them, or is postfix just complaining that I hang up prematurely?

Comment: @user1968963 - you could try changing the command `QUIT` to a dot `.`. I'd also try taking the `QUIT` out entirely.

Comment: @slm - a dot `.` does not work even in telnet. And without the `QUIT` the connection hangs until the specified 5 seconds elapse. I think, postfix does not like that the `QUIT` arrives together with the `HELO`.

Comment: @user1968963 - I use sendmail. Have never used postfix. The dot was suggested previously so I thought perhaps that would work here. I believe the standard RFC for SMTP says to use `QUIT`.

Comment: @slm - is there any chance of getting rid of the error message?

Comment: @user1968963 - in searching for a solution I'm coming up empty. This seems to be a bit of an issue with Postfix, best I can tell.

Comment: @slm - when I get rid of the `HELO` part and only leave `QUIT` I get no error and it seems to work fine. Thus, my minimalistic solution: `echo QUIT | nc -w5 mail.bubba.net 25 ; echo $?`

Comment: @user1968963 - that works for me too. I'll incorporate that into the overall A. Thanks!

Comment: @user1968963 - updated!